# Seekbar timing on Android

Tags: android, timing, seekbar

I have an mediaplayer with seekbar. And the seekbar works fine. My problem is, I need to show the progressing time at the beginning of the seekbar, and remaining time at the end of the seekbar in a textview. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure i really understand how you want it. But if you have a seekbar with a set maximum to the end time, and this is moving during the song/video/whatever you could just call `mySeekBar.getProgress()`. Otherwise if you have a onSeekBarChangedListener you get the progress from the implemented method. Otherwise just just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the beggining and subtract the current time with the start time each time the seekbar changes.